# Adding and re-fetching array data in vuex

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuex

I have data in this format which i am getting from an api https://pastebin.ubuntu.com/p/gTJ6vCykzr/

In my vuex state

```
state: {
    hoteldata:[]
},
  mutations: {
    FETCH_HOTEL_DATA: (state, payload) => {        
      state.hoteldata = payload
    },
```

and this is what i am using to set the hotels data into the vuex state

```
getHotels() {
console.log(this.country);
console.log(this.search_query);
  return axios.post('https://example.com.php',
    { country: this.country,
      search_query: this.search_query
    },
    { headers: {
    'Content-type': 'application/json',
    }
  }).then((response) => {
   
     //console.log('response: ' + response.data.images_results);
     
     Object.entries(response.data.images_results).forEach(([key, value]) => {
        this.$store.commit('FETCH_HOTEL_DATA', value);
        console.log(value);
        });
    console.log('state at this point...displays one row', this.$store.state.hoteldata);
  }).catch( error => { 
    console.log('error: ' + error); 
  });
}
```

How can i add all rows of data returned in the api?.

Second, when i make another api call, shall the data previously in the store be replaced by the new data or shall vuex add the new data without caring about duplicates?

Comment: Just to be certain, `getHotels()` is a Vuex action, rather than a getter, correct?

Comment: getHotels() is a method, i haven't mappedGetters in my code which i think i should have.

Comment: I've never done it before, but [via the documentation](https://vuex.vuejs.org/guide/mutations.html#committing-mutations-in-components), there's nothing syntactically wrong with calling mutations from components, I don't think there should be any problems with this code (I've just always called mutations exclusively from store actions). Is there a particular reason you're calling `Object.entries()` and `forEach()` on the `images_results` array, rather than committing it to store directly?

Comment: I am doing a shortcut although i know better.Anyway, there is nothing preventing me from doing exactly that;adding entire json as received from api. I have done that and used my getter to display the data.

Comment: I have the entire response in my store as json but now, what is the equivalent of  Object.entries in vue, how do i loop through it?

Comment: Maybe I'm misunderstanding, but I don't know why you'd *need* `Object.entries()` on an array; you can loop through an array natively already, that's kinda the point of an array, whether using [`forEach()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach) or otherwise.

Comment: You aren't wrong in that understanding. I was the one over the problem complex. I can now loop over and the getter came in handy.